# Title: This Site Can't be reached

Tags: browser

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Without doing anything issue started all of sudden and stopped accessing websites from browser

Some websites are working and some are not even google not working

I am able to access stack overflow(But only first page and getting error at top "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load. Retry using another source."), amazon, flipkart from browser but not any banking websites and shows below error

"This Site Can't be reached"
Unexpectedly closed the connection
Try:
Checking the connection.
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Till now I tried with below things

1. Uninstalled & installed Google Chrome
2. Tried to update certificates in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the following steps.**

```
01. Open Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)
02. cd /etc
03. Search for "Resolv.config"
04. Copy "Resolv.config" name
05. Type sudo nano resolv.config and enter
06. Add comment i.e "#" before nameserver
07. Now add these two nameservers
    nameserver 8.8.8.8
    nameserver 8.8.4.4
08. Press Ctrl+X and press Y then hit enter
09. Now restart the network manager by this command
    sudo service manager-network restart

NOW THE NETWORK WILL RESTART. 

10. Use any browsers and you can check.
```

***HOPE THIS WORK!***

If this not working follow this article. Sometimes will help this is for you. [`This site can't be reached Error`](http://net-informations.com/q/mis/reached.html)